# Dynamically loaded JavaScript file and non-ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, dynamic, scripting, loading, ondemand

I have the following problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("1. ČĆŽŠĐčćžšđ");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Tst.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var pScript = document.createElement("script");
 pScript.type = "text/javascript";
 pScript.src = "Tst.js";
 pScript.charset = "windows-1250";
 $("body").append(pScript);
</script>
```

(These are Croatian characters.)

Contents of Tst.js is:

```
alert("2. ČĆŽŠĐčćžšđ");
```

Output of this script in FireFox (and Safari, so I've concluded that this is not the problem with the browser, but my code):

```
1. ČĆŽŠĐčćžšđ
2. ČĆŽŠĐčćžšđ
2. �Ǝ���枚�
```

Charset on the main page that is calling this code is Windows-1250.

I don't understand why when I call Tst.js statically (by `<script src="Tst.js" type="text/javascript"></scipt>`) the characters are shown normal, but when I dynamically include Tst.js the characters go bannanas...

And unfortunately I can't port all my code to UTF-8.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2nd update:** Specifying the encoding in the content-type header of the JavaScript file did the trick - for whatever reason!

**Update:** You are setting the character set *after loading the script*. 
Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var pScript = document.createElement("script");
 pScript.type = "text/javascript";
 pScript.charset = "windows-1250";
 pScript.src = "Tst.js";
 $("body").append(pScript);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, both files are in windows-1250. That's why it is so strange.

Comment: Now I've changed the order of charset and src attributes so the charset is before src but the problem persists.

Comment: @Stazh Really strange. What happens if you add `charset="windows-1250"` to example 2 (where you include the script using a script tag)?

Comment: Nothing :) It works fine :) And when I set charset to something different it also works and renders characters fine. It's like the charset attr is ignored.

And when I load the script dynamically it's like it is beeing loaded to some separate page with unset or wrongly set charset. But strange enough, the functions from Tst.js if I add them work just fine, with no problems, only with Croatian characters.

Comment: @Stazh You mention Webkit so I'm not 100% sure it's relevant but still: "Currently Netscape/Mozilla does not fully support the W3C HTML standard charset attribute in resource links; e.g.: Anchor, LINK, SCRIPT." http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/intl/browser/charsethandling/testcase-CharsetHandlingII.html Ideas to try: 1. encoding the script file as UTF-8 and setting the `charset` property accordingly (to try out whether it's limited to UTF-8 and ISO) 2. sending a `content-type` header in the js embed file, using web server settings or a scripting language like PHP.

Comment: @Stazh and by the way, there is no AJAX involved here is it? Because Ajax requests go through as utf-8 by default.

Comment: @Pekka: Yes, when I set the header explicitly to charset=windows-1250 it works just fine!

Thank you Pekka very much :)

( I'm new here to stackoverflow.com so is there any system of reputation here so i can give you rep+ or something? )

Comment: @Stazh cheers, glad it works and this is very good to know! Upvoting and accepting answers is the way of giving reputation around here, so everything's fine.

Comment: Oh and @Stazh make sure you check whether setting the header works for IE 6 / 7 / 8 to avoid surprises.

Comment: I'm creating web application not web site so I have the privilege to mandate what kind of browser must be used with the web app and decided not to support IE 6 and 7 :)

Thanks a lot again :)